# WPF AutoCompleteText - Solution that doesn't lag / lock UI on popup generation

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, autocomplete

I have tried about 4-5 different WPF solutions so far, including the WPF Toolkit and gradonz.actb (my favorite option) but every single one seems to be lagging when creating the dropdown.  Once the dropdown is there, the data loads extremely fast, but on initial creation it is lagged and locks my UI.  And this is not just a one time thing, each time it is created it appears to have a second or two lag / UI locking (I am assuming while it creates the object in my tree).

In advance I do know it is not my datasource as I have traced it and it never takes under 10 milliseconds to return to the search providers. I am also returning just 20 items max to the provider, so there is no reason that I can see for this delay. The problem is when it generates the list to show, and it happens on all of the solutions I have found.

Even if you know a licensed one that works well, I am willing to spend to solve this.

I appreciate any help

Anthony Greco

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the popup class was lagging on show and it popped it up each time a new result started.  A hack around this was popup on load, and when we don't need it, set the height to 0.  Not ideal, but after 4 hours, at least it works.